# vba Removing spaces before and after certain symbols and also check and insert these symbols if one is missing

Tags: vba, excel

This is part of the vba code. I removed trailing spaces at begining and end of the text using `TRIM()` but how do I remove spaces before and after certain symbols and make sure that the symbols are used right.

> Eg1: Apple : ;  is red => Apple:;is red
>
> Eg2: Orange:; is sweet => Orange:;is sweet
>
> Eg3: Mango::smells good => Mango:;smells good

So basically if there is a space/spaces before ":" and after and also before ";" and after this symbol it has to be removed.In the third example where symbol ":" is used twice instead of ";" as the second symbol.So it has to replace with ";" the second time.

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: _3.  Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._ -[Help Center: What's On Topic Here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I wanted to know  if their is a way without listing all the possible ways a person by mistake enters differently by using `.Replace`

Answer (score 3):

Select the all the cells and run this:

```
Sub foo4()
Selection.Replace " ; ", ";"
Selection.Replace " : ", ":"
Selection.Replace "; ", ";"
Selection.Replace ": ", ":"
Selection.Replace " ;", ";"
Selection.Replace " :", ":"
Selection.Replace "::", ":;"
End Sub
```